# how to create php script to send emails in ionic application

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm building an application and one of the tasks in this app is sending is emails to the users,
I've searched for a way to accomplish this task and found several ways
One of them is php script, But I have no idea how to create this script or how to integrate it in ionic 3

So I want to ask if anyone has an example Or a link to learn how to do it, please Share it with me and people who have the same problem,